# Getting a Property from a PowerShell String

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following line to get the relevant details from users in our domain:

```
$NeverUser=Get-ADUser -Properties displayname,sAmAccountName,pwdlastset,mail  -Filter{userAccountControl -eq 512} -SearchBase "OU=xx,DC=xx,DC=local" | select displayname,sAmAccountName,pwdlastset,mail
```

Now, from the var `$NeverUser` I want to get the property `displayname`and allocate it to another var.
Something like:

```
$Name = $NeverUser.displayname
```

Comment: your code is correct

Comment: What you have is how you would access that property.  I'll assume that didn't work which means that perhaps there is something funky with the contents of $NeverUser. Take a look at the members on the object like so `$NeverUser | Get-Member`.  Does displayname show up?

Comment: @KeithHill I get a `System.String displayname=xxxx`

Comment: OK, now try this: `$NeverUser | Format-List *`.  Is there a value in displayname or is it empty?

Comment: @KeithHill Lots of entries like this: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData`

Comment: Do *not* tack on a Format-* command at the end of this line `$NeverUser = Get-ADUser ...`.  Format commands like Format-Table and Format-List should rarely be used on a line that is being assigned to a variable.  You want to assign objects with interesting data to that $NeverUser variable and not the output of Format commands (which are basically formatting instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Further down the script I used a foreach-loop and was still trying to access the property of $NeverUser instead of the new var. @KeithHill made me realise this..

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.